# Parameters passed to function disappear after await

Tags: javascript

In the below code, after the await, the user_message and bot arguments disappear, and I don't understand why.

```
const process_user_message = async ({user_message, bot}) => {
  console.log('before await…')
  console.log(user_message)                     // logs lovely big object
  console.log(typeof user_message)              // logs 'object'
  df_result = await df_query({
    query: user_message.text,
    session_id: user_message.channel,
    bot: bot
  })
  console.log('after await…')
  console.log(user_message)                     // logs nothing :(
  console.log(typeof user_message)              // logs nothing :(

  bus.emit('message from dialogflow', {
    bot,
    df_result,
    user_message
  })
}
```

Comment: Is it logging `'after await…'`?

Comment: df_result is undefined

Comment: Is the object `user_message` being changed outside the context of function  `process_user_message`. As Objects are in JavaScript are `passed by reference` .

Comment: You seem to be missing a few semicolons.

Comment: that's fine, semicolons are not mandatory in JS

Comment: this works => https://repl.it/repls/FlakyFabulousBases. You should share more info, like the fact that you probably are using Vue (bc of `bus.emit`)

Comment: Seems like you need a `const` or `let` before `df_result`. Your function is probably throwing uncaught errors, and if so, you should address that as well.

Comment: Thanks for all your thoughts, folks. Here's the above code in context: https://github.com/Citizen-AI/rentbot-webchat-server/blob/master/Dialogflow/test.js

@MarkMeyer yes, it does log 'after await…'
LawrenceCherone df_result does correctly populate
NishantJain no user_message is not changed outside the function
JohnWu sorry; I'm a Coffeescript guy myself so semi-allergic
JLRishe can you tell me more about the uncaught error possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like df_result was never defined.

```
const process_user_message = async ({user_message, bot}) => {
  const df_result = await df_query({
    query: user_message.text,
    session_id: user_message.channel,
    bot: bot
  });
  console.log(typeof user_message)
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @sreeram. I've fixed that to no avail.

Comment: @user1876628 Please put it in a try catch block and see what's the error.

Comment: Thanks @sreeram. I put the const df_result = ...; into try/catch. No error. If I force an error, e.g. by renaming the functional call df_query to xdf_query, I do get an error, but the console.log(typeof user_message) and console.log(user_message) then work correctly.